# How to detect if Mouse stopped moving in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do a Game like slither.io in Unity but it's hard to detect when the mouse stopped moving, I want the ball to not stop, instead it should move on, worked several hours on this problem but can't quite get it to work. I thought if I save where the last known position is I can keep the velocity but I don't know how to implement yet.

Thanks in advance!

This is my Source Code:

```
private float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
[SerializeField] float constantSpeed = 100f;
[SerializeField] float padding = 5f;
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
private Vector3 mousePosition;
private Vector2 direction;
private List<Vector3> ListPos = new List<Vector3>();
private Vector3 empty;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    empty = Vector3.zero;
    SetUpMoveBoundaries();
    rb2D = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () { 
    Move();
}

private void SetUpMoveBoundaries()
{
    Camera gameCamera = Camera.main;
    xMin = gameCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).x + padding;
    xMax = gameCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, 0)).x - padding;
    yMin = gameCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).y + padding;
    yMax = gameCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, 0)).y - padding;
}

private void Move()
{

    if (Input.mousePosition != empty)
    {
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        direction = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;
        ListPos.Add(direction);
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * constantSpeed, direction.y * constantSpeed);
    }

    else
    {
        var last = ListPos.LastOrDefault();
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(last.x * constantSpeed, last.y * constantSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried to write? Also, how is the included code relevant to the question?

Comment: Look at my Move Method, the if statement shows that i tried to get if the mouseposition is zero or not

Comment: It makes more sense to save `Input.MousePosition`in a vector at the end of your update and check if it is same as the previous frame value at the beginning of update than checking if it is zero

Comment: do you want to set up a minimal inerval after which you treat the mouse at stopped? if you don't, you'll occasionally get false positives when mouse will report the same position twice in a row even though its actually moving

Comment: Im open for any kind of Solution for this Problem @zambari

Comment: I´ll try it out @Ali Kanat

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want it to trigger one of the two functions depending on whether the mouse has moved or not since last frame:

```
Vector2 lastMousePosition;
void WhenMouseIsMoving()
{
}
void WhenMouseIsntMoving()
{
}
void Update()
{
 if (Input.mousePosition!=lastMousePosition)
 {
   lastMousePosition=Input.MousePosition;
   WhenMouseIsMoving();
  } else
   WhenMouseIsntMoving();
}
```

You'll need to add one more bool variable to keep track of whether it has just started or stopped moving;

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for mouse movement without having to keep track of the mouse position in a variable, you can use the `GetAxis` function from Unity's `Input` class.

To do this you will have to make sure that mouse movement is hooked up to axes in Unity's input manager. It is normally there by default already, with 'Mouse X' and 'Mouse Y' mapped to the mouse delta for their respective axes.

For example:

```
// Is true when the mouse has moved
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
{
    // Do something with mouse input
}
```

In your case, it looks like you could do something like this as your move function:

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
if (direction.magnitude != 0)
{
    // ListPos.Add(direction);
    rb2D.velocity = direction.normalized * constantSpeed;
}
```

---

As an unrelated note, your `ListPos` variable is growing in size potentially every frame without limit. If you need to keep track of previous positions for reasons other than your attempt at detecting mouse position changes, you should consider how much storage you will need and give it a fixed size replacing the oldest entries, or consider whether or not the values need to be independent or can be merged instead.